# Microphone Volume Resets to 46 when Switching Playback Device

Tags: windows-10, audio, microphone

Using Windows 10 Pro Ver.1803 on Asrock Z270M-ITX board. Only one audio in device connected: microphone plugged into rear 3.5mm mic in. Three audio out devices connected in total: headphone plugged into front 3.5mm audio out; JBL Pebbles plugged into USB; monitor speaker connected via HDMI.

Problem is, when I change the default audio out device, the microphone level resets to 46 without reason. If I unplug the microphone and plug it in again, the microphone level resets to 46 too. I can change the level to 100 manually, but since I switch between headphone and speaker constantly, I need to do this every time. Seems like whenever any changes are made to my audio device settings, the level reset would happen. And always to 46.

I've already went through all the usual suspects, including programs automatically adjusting microphone levels, untick allow exclusive control, select do nothing during communications etc. Problem persists. Has anyone had any experience with this specific symptom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved after a driver update and reboot...

I guess I should have taken my own advice to many common electronics issues - "have you tried turning it off and back on again?"